# Sharing ActiveRecord::Base enums across models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

I have 2 models

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum state: [:draft, :ready]
end

class Creation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum state: [:draft, :ready]
end
```

As you can see both Models have define **state** enum. I'd like to get rid of this repetition and move **state** somewhere else.

How can I do that, while keeping all useful thing like `Author.ready` and automatic conversion between integers in database and strings in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concerns` like below.

```
module SimpleState
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    enum state: [:draft, :ready]
  end
end
```

Then include it in your models like below

```
#author.rb
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SimpleState
end

#creation.rb
class Creation < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SimpleState
end
```